# How do I get access to a Javascript client SDK generated by swagger in a web page?

Tags: javascript, browser, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am working on a REST API for a web-service.  We have chosen to create a formal specification of the API using SwaggerHub.  Now I've come to the next step, using the generated Javascript client SDK to talk to the web-service in a web page...

The documentation provided by SwaggerHub is focused on using the generated client SDK in node.js, which seems to behave slightly different from a browser.

I've collected the full SDK in a single bundle using "browserify":

```
browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

Then I've added a reference to the bundle to the HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

This seems to work, although I'm unsure exactly how I can test it at this stage.

Then I try to interact with the API declared in the bundle, as soon as the document is ready (this is - except for the encapsulation and the `alert()` calls - taken from the documentation provided in the generated client SDK):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('Document ready');
        var WebApiForStandard = require('web_api_for_standard');
        alert('API ready');
        var defaultClient = WebApiForStandard.ApiClient.instance;
        [...]
```

I get the "Document ready" message, and I don't get the "API ready" message.  When I check the browser console (in Firefox), it shows:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I assume that this is because `require()` is something from node.js.

... but I've already asked the browser to load the API bundle, so maybe that isn't a problem.  Next try is to omit the `require()` call:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('Document ready');
        var defaultClient = WebApiForStandard.ApiClient.instance;
        alert('Client ready');
        [...]
```

But no.  Now the browser console reports:

```
ReferenceError: WebApiForStandard not defined
```

What do I do then?